# Is qualified name in the member function declaration allowed?

Tags: c++, c++11, grammar, qualified-name, member-functions

This code is accepted by MSVC9.0. My question is whether it is legal according to the standard (the old and/or the new one). A quote would be very much welcome, too.

```
class X
{
   void X::f();
};
```

Comment: @Oli This fails on GCC 4.2, so it would be good to know if it's GCC failing or if it's VC++ not following the standard.

Comment: I don't know if it's allowed, but it does not make sense - you can not write anything else then `X::` there.

Comment: @Oli: Yes, it does. Curiosity is not a sin ;)

Comment: @Armen: Hmm.  Curiosity makes sense if it's something you're ever likely to encounter in practice.  Are you ever likely to encounter this in practice?

Comment: @Oli: As a matter of fact, I HAVE encountered it in practice. I was doing code review and the author has written something like this. I wrote an issue saying it's not normal, and he said it's no difference to qualify it or not. So I asked to make sure

Comment: Even the GCC 3 rejects it when compiled with `-pedantic`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, this is not valid.  Here, `X::f` is a qualified name; you are attempting to use it as a *declarator-id*.  C++03 8.3[dcl.meaning]/1 lists the circumstances under which a *declarator-id* may be qualified:

> A *declarator-id* shall not be qualified except for
>
> - the definition of a member function or static data member outside
>     of its class,
> - the definition or explicit instantiation of a function or variable member of a namespace outside
>     of its namespace, or
> - the definition of a previously declared explicit specialization outside of its namespace, or
> - the declaration of a friend function that is a member of another class or namespace.

Because `X::f` falls into none of these four categories, it is incorrect.

The rule that requires the definition of a member function outside of the class definition to be qualified can be found at C++03 9.3[class.mfct]/5:

> If the definition of a member function is lexically outside its class definition, the member function name shall be qualified by its class name using the `::` operator.

Comment: Thank you, James, your answer is perfect, but Als was twelve seconds faster, so I accepted his answer :)

Comment: My +1, Because this answer has better explanation of quote from the standard, and it will be even understandable by Non Standerdese fans.If I was Armen I would accept this as the answer.

Comment: 12 seconds faster and 12 percent less beautifully formatted :)

Comment: @Als, OK then, if you don't mind, then, I'll accept this one :)

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: I don't mind at all, Infact, Happy that you made the right choice. I believe **The answer which is correct & Best explains the problem & the solution to it should be accepted not the first correct answer.** :)

Comment: @Als: To be perfectly honest, both your answers explain the issue in its entirety, it's difficult to compare two good answer

Answer (score 7):

As I understand it is **Not valid** as per the C++03 Specification.

**Reference - C++03 standard:**

**Section $8.3:**

*Each declarator contains exactly one declarator-id; it names the identifier that is declared. The id-expression of a declarator-id shall be a simple identifier except for the declaration of some special functions (12.3, 12.4, 13.5) and for the declaration of template specializations or partial specializations (14.7). **A declarator-id shall not be qualified except for the definition of a member function (9.3) or static data member (9.4) or nested class (9.7) outside of its class,** the definition or explicit instantiation of a function, variable or class member of a namespace outside of its namespace, or the definition of a previously declared explicit specialization outside of its namespace, or the declaration of a friend function that is a member of another class or namespace (11.4).*

I hope I am deriving the appropriate meaning of the above. I will admit reading & understanding the quotes from the Standard makes me a little dizzy. Let me know if I interpret it wrongly.